VS Code Codespace wont run task
Im currently using VS Code Codespace through Cengage for my SQL class. Ive been using it all semester and its wokred fine. It lets me run the code on VS code but when i git the check task button to check my work to show completed or wrong the icon acts like its going to work starts spinning then just stops and doesnt check my work. It wont let me check my work so i cant complete my assignment. I dont know what to do Ive tried all i can think of. It wont let me delete the repository because its through and organization it says. Ive made a new github account and tried that way and it wont work still. Please can someone help me.
Logged out waited couple hours logged back in still nothing. Made a new github account tried that way and it wouldnt work the page wouldnt even load right gave me error couldnt find page screen.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
